# Permission denied in SSH to Debian 8.5 using root user although PermitRootLogin is yes

Tags: ssh, login, debian-jessie

I'm trying to SSH to my Debian 8.5 using `root` user. The password is correct because I can login to Debian using local console. `PermitRootLogin` is equal to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and server is restarted multiple time to insure that this change is taken.

```
grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes
```

How can i solve this problem?

Running `sudo tail /var/log/auth.log`:

```
Nov 29 07:40:06 mydeb sshd[2530]: User root from ::1 not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
Nov 29 07:40:06 mydeb sshd[2530]: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]
Nov 29 07:40:07 mydeb sshd[2530]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=root
Nov 29 07:40:09 mydeb sshd[2530]: Failed password for invalid user root from ::1 port 41079 ssh2
Nov 29 07:40:14 mydeb sshd[2530]: Failed password for invalid user root from ::1 port 41079 ssh2
Nov 29 07:40:16 mydeb sshd[2530]: Failed password for invalid user root from ::1 port 41079 ssh2
Nov 29 07:40:16 mydeb sshd[2530]: Connection closed by ::1 [preauth]
Nov 29 07:40:16 mydeb sshd[2530]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=root
```

Comment: what do the server logs say?

Comment: You means syslog?

Comment: Add output of `sudo tail /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Assign password of root user by command `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: As i said in my question: _The password is correct because I can login to Debian using local console._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add `root` at the of line which is started with `AllowGroups`. The line should be like this:

```
AllowGroups sudo sshuser root
```

Restart `ssh` service by following command:

```
service ssh restart
```